# How to compare two columns in netsuite in a saved Search

Tags: oracle, netsuite

I have two columns Vendor Account (in the bill) and the default payables account in the vendor record. We have some wrong postings and I want to create a saved search to control this.
I've isolated the account number and default account number, however i can't seem to create a formula column that compares them (with a case formula i.e)

Is it because one of the account columns might be in text? What are the problems that can be happening here?

[Columns to be compared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUeKq.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that "Vendor Account" and "Vendor Payables Account" are both number/integer fields the following case statement should work.  Be sure to replace the field ids to match your account.

```
CASE WHEN {VendorAccount}={VendorPayablesAccount} THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END
```

If the fields are not number fields use the following:

```
CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER({VendorAccount}) = TO_NUMBER({VendorPayablesAccount}) THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END
```